# popToRootViewController from NSObject Class

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, rootviewcontroller

I have been trying to find the solution but none of them available are working for me, Can someone please advise how can I achieve this?

I have set a rootviewcontroller as a view controller(Container Viewcontroller) by using the following code after successful login.

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerViewController") as! ContainerViewController
 let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = vc
```

Based on a specific notification received, I have defined a custom function which is being called for sure but I want my app user to go back to root automatically regardless of the navigation controller he is currently on. I am using this code

```
 guard let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
 navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Flow is Root(VC)->NavigationController1->PushingViewController2->PushingViewController3, suppose user is currently at ViewController3(which is pushed) and I want to take the user back from anotherClass NSOBject which is observing network Status and upon network failure it is calling ABC function but when I add the above navigation controller reference to pop all navigationcontrollers it is not working.

Comment: Your use of `popToRootViewController` assumes you have been pushing view controllers onto the window's root navigation controller. But your "flow" seems to indicate you are presenting more and more navigation controllers, not pushing them. Even more, is `window.rootViewController` a navigation controller?

Comment: rmaddy my container view is a viewcontroller and I have set the it as root after that I am pushing a parent navigation controller and on top of it I am pushing viewcontroller. so the flow sorry for the mistake which I will also correct above is root(viewcontroller) -> pushing Navigation Controller -> then Pushing ViewController